# Php error log 404 and redirect to home page

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have this code below that handles 404 errors but i like to redirect all the 404 errors to home page, here is what i have:

```
function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
{
    $heading = "404 Page Not Found";
    $message = "The page you requested was not found.";

    // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it
    if ($log_error)
    {
        log_message('error', '404 Page Not Found --> '.$page);
    }

    echo $this->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_404', 404);
    exit;
}
```

How can i redirect to home page instead of giving 404 error.

Comment: Redirect to the homepage, then display the actual error?

Comment: `header("location: index.php")` , are you wondering how to redirect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php header redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934357/php-header-redirect)

Comment: the code above is what i have at the moment, i just want to redirect to home page, nothing more.

Comment: @user2969009, so as Sam says `header("location: index.php")`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Do ***NOT*** return anything but a 404 status for a non-existant resource. Search engine crawlers and other automated utilities will function incorrectly at best, and DoS your site offline at worst.

The *only* case in which issuing a redirect from a 404 response would be considered acceptable is in the case of an actual user with an actual browser, and in this case you can use a `<meta>` redirect to achieve the same effect without breaking HTTP.

eg:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/index.php'" />
```

Just serve a lightweight page containing the directive in the `<head>` section and you will avoid 100% of the doom and gloom I've predicted.